# NetworkManager: IPv6 Automatic Modes

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, ipv6, automatic

I was looking at the IPv6 config of my Ethernet connection in NetworkManager's connection editor. It seems there are 3 automatic modes alongside other options:

- Automatic
- Automatic, addresses only
- Automatic, DHCP only

Can anyone help me with the differences between these options?

P.S. There are 2 following options in IPv4 settings and their difference is obvious to me.

- Automatic(DHCP)
- Automatic(DHCP) addresses only